# Merging ontologies with same IRI

Tags: merge, ontology, protege, iri

I am trying to merge ontologies having same IRI using Protege tool. This doesn't seem to be happening. Is there any way to do it without  the code?

If this is not possible,  is there a way to merge the classes having same IRI?

I also want to know if there is a method to refer to one Ontology from multiple ontologies

Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Can you add more details? The code Errors you are getting?

Comment: Referring to an ontology form multiple ontologies is what ontology imports do. You can import an ontology from Protege with ease.

Comment: Depending on the format of your ontology file, merging can be as simple as a copy-paste.

Comment: @Ignazio Thank you! I could find the option of importing the ontology in the 'Ontology imports' tab

Comment: @Richard-Degenne Yes i am able to merge / copy / move entities. But i was wondering if we can merge ontologies having the same IRI.

Comment: What you call "merging ontologies" consists in fact in copying all entities of the first ontology into the other one.